# Django: Heroku deploy not migrating properly

Tags: django, git, heroku, django-models, django-migrations

I'm new to Heroku and I am trying to do my first deploy with a change in my models. Now I already have some important stuff in my app's database that I don't want to lose (I'm using PostgresSQL).

Anyway, I did those few improvement to my app's model and it works alright locally, but when I try to deploy it just gives me the

```
Internal Server Error: /lares/

ProgrammingError at /lares/
column lares_imovel.referencia does not exist
```

I am used to throwing `makemigrations` and `migrate` locally and than just `git push heroku master`

Anyway, I also tried the `heroku run python manage.py migrate` afterwards, but I get the same result every time.

I deleted all my migrations files and created them again for this particular app, still it works locally and the issue remains on production.

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

I don't know if any of my code is necessary, I'm pretty sure the problem is not there, but if requested I can post it here.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried removing all the new itens to the models and it worked fine. I guess there is something more to adding stuff to django models on heroku that I am still unaware of.

Comment: The command `makemigrations` creates new `.py` files on disk. Did you add them to the repository using `git add -A .` first?

Comment: Yes, I am tracking changes to the migrations folder. Usually I run `makemigrations` locally and `migrate` with no problems there, but I also tried these commands on heroku (both of them) with no luck.

Comment: use `showmigrations` to check if there is a missing migration to apply

Comment: I tried it. But I can't find a consistent answer. I see that Heroku doesn't automatically runs the migrations, so I have to run them myself. After I did it it showed that all migrations were applied, but the error message remains the same
`Internal Server Error: /lares/

ProgrammingError at /lares/
column lares_imovel.referencia does not exist
LINE 1: ...ares_imovel"."complemento", "lares_imovel"."cep", "lares_imo...`

I still have no clue why my migrations are not creating new fields to my models.

Comment: Could you share the Installed_Apps from your settings file?

Comment: Actually I started over and got it right. Something along the way must have been wrong. Now it works, but I don't know what the problem was.